# What issues will I have with my financial accounts after a name change?

Tags: united-states

I have been considering having my name legally changed. A concern is what types of financial issues this would cause. If I have accounts in my (current) name and I get my name legally changed would there be some issue accessing the account? What (if any) types of issues can arise from having your name legally changed.

Comment: People change their names all the time when they get married.  It shouldn't be any more trouble than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding your bank accounts - if you get your name changed through the courts you'll have a copy of the court order. Take it to the bank and they'll take it from there.

Regarding issues that can arise - you'll have to deal with Social Security, employers, the post office, driver's licenses, cable providers etc etc etc it's a long list. All of it will be simple enough if you have the legal docs proving the change, but it will take time and effort to address the needs of each agency. Be ready for hours of tedium. And remember that some of these folks will be charging you a fee for the change.

This SC site has a good amount of basic info including some of the things you will need to get the change approved: http://www.scfamilylaw.com/articles/name-change/

It's not a big deal - ask any woman who changed her name with marriage - but it will be time consuming.

And by the way - it's worth noting that the court doesn't have to grant a change.

Comment: +1. Two things to consider. First, when deciding to change your name think twice so that you don't want to change it again and undergo the same process. Second, find the laws that state the exact requirements for the name change so that you're don't suddenly find out a change is not possible when you least expect it.